# is the final price function is not compatible with Collection of product?

Tags: magento2, price

I am creating a product collection using some of the product IDs as per this code:

```
$data = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection')
            ->addIdFilter($product_ids)
            ->setStore($this->_storeModelStoreManagerInterface->getStore())
            ->addStoreFilter()
            //->addFinalPrice()
            ->addAttributeToSelect($this->getUsedMagentoAttributes());
```

By looping the product collection I am getting the product entity by this method:

```
 $item = $data->getItemById($product['product_id']);
```

I am trying to get the final price of the product using the Magento 2 function `$item->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount()->getValue()` but i am not able to get the correct final price(special/sale price).

Please note, I have commented the addFinalPrice() in the collection as this creates the issue while adding the tax amounts.
Also, I do not want to use the product object by load() method as it takes too much time to process.

Please suggest.